# Broken Calculator

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

**Problem Statement:**

There is a broken calculator. Only a few of the digits [`0 to 9`] and operators [`+, -, *, /`] are working.

A req no. needs to be formed using the working digits and the operators. Each press on the keyboard is called an operation.

- `=` operator is always working and is used when the req no. is formed using operators.
- `-1` needs to be printed in case the req no. cannot be formed using the digits and the operators provided OR exceeds the max no. of operations allowed.
- At no point in time during the calculation of the result, the no. should become negative or exceed 999 [`0 <= calcno <= 999`]

**Input:**

- 1st line contains 3 space separated nos: no. of working digits, no. of working operators, max. no of operations allowed.
- 2nd line contains space separated working digits.
- 3rd line contains space separated working operators [`1` represents `+`, `2` represents `-`, `3` represents `*`, `4` represents `/`].
- 4th line contains the req. no to be formed.

**Output:**

Find the *minimum required* operations to form the req no.

---

*Example:*

**Input 1:**

```
2 1 8  
2 5  
3  
50
```

**Possible ways:**

*Case 1:* `2*5*5` = -> `6 operations`
*Case 2:* `2*25` = -> `4 operations`

> 4 is the req Answer

---

**Input 2:**

```
3 4 8  
5 4 2  
3 2 4 1  
42
```

**Possible ways:**
Case 1: `42` -> `2 operations` (direct key in)
Case 2: `5*4*2+2` = -> `8 operations`
..........some other ways

> 2 is the req Answer

---

I am not getting a proper approach to this problem.
Can someone suggest some ways to approach the problem.

Comment: What is the max number of operations that can be allowed?

Comment: Use BFS to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you had any concrete ideas thus far about how to solve this problem (beyond "maybe I can use DP or recursion")? Some people might be hesitant to help if there isn't a visible attempt to solve the problem by the asker.

Comment: Do the operations have some precedence or can we assume that evaluation is done from left to right, i,e, `1+2*3 = 3*3 = 9`?

Comment: @Codor I am curious why is that relevant?

Comment: @GijsDenHollander It is relevant because it decides whether a proposed sequence of input numbers and operators generates the target value or not.

Comment: @Codor In the way the  question is formulated its clear that '1+2*3 is not 3*3 = 9'. one take 5 operations and the other 3. And if you're lookign for minimum amount of operations requered, why would you want to express it in a more complex way?

Comment: "2*25= -> 4 operations" should that not be 5 operations if each button press is an operation?

Comment: Youre correct only the = operator is not counted. See problem description ^^.

Comment: Actually considering each press to be an operation adds to the difficulty. Also, I have kind of bizarre question. Can we just add a digit to a result? What I mean is, let numbers be: `0,2`, operations: `*` and desired result: `42`. Is this allowed => `2 * 2 2`? As `2*2` gives 4 and we add 2 to make it `42`.

Comment: Looking at the problem description this is not allowed, its still a caclulator you are using. But this would give answers with less operations:)

Comment: @Codor, your point is correct. Although I think, it should be left to right preceding, as a calculator does, and not applying BODMAS rules as 6th grade arithmetic problems.

Comment: @Codor   Yes, the evaluation is left to right as is done in a calculator.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I have updated the question with the same.

Comment: @Dukeling   No, I could not get anything concrete to solve the problem. The only way I could think of is to handle all the fifteen combinations of the operators separately. I should have added other tags like bfs etc. to the problem statement.

Comment: Can we assume _division_ to be integral division, i.e. the integral part of the quotient?

Comment: @Codor  No, the division 5 / 2 = 2.5  and not 2

Comment: @Chris  You are correct. The number of operations is 5 . Sorry about that. I will update the same in the problem statement

Comment: @Gijs Den Hollander  = is counted as an operation. Just that = operator is always in working state.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question)[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving some more context what vish4071 said in the comments.

Set up a graph in the following way:
Starting the graph with a root, and than the new node are the number you're aloud to use (for the example this is 2 and 5). And build up the graph level by level. 
Make each level in the following way, a new node will consist either of adding number or a operator which you're aloud to use. After each operator there cannot be another operator.

If the node has a higher value than the Target value, than kill the node (target as end note), this only works for this example (if the operators are * and +).  If you would be able to use the - and / operator this is not vallid.

Do this till you find the required value, and the level (+1, due to the = operation) is you're answer.

And example of the graph is given below

```
for your first example:
D=0    D=1    
       5
      /
Root /
     \
      \2


D=1    D=2   d=3   d=4
            --2
           / 
          /
        (*)___5  --> reaches answer but at level 6
        /   
       /     (*)___2  --> complete
      /     /   \  5
     /     /
  2 /____25_252    --> end node
    \     \
     \     \ 
      \     
       \    225    --> end node
        \  /
         22__222   --> end node
           \            
            (*)
```

This is slightly better than brute forcing, maybe there is a more optimal way.

Comment: Since OP asked only for `some ways to approach the problem`, I think this answer suffices. But you have missed a lot of detail on implementation and a couple of things are incorrect, like you kill the node if it has value higher than target, which would not give correct answer to [2],[+,/],[3], which is achievable as `2+2+2/2`.

PS: I did not write the answer myself because it is too much of work ;P

Comment: @vish4071 
 
youre correct, I will edit my answer in a sec. What have I further missed? Id id have some free time:)

Comment: Some implementation details were missing, like you can always use a hash-table of size 1000 to check for visit nodes, initially create all possible 1,2 and 3 digit numbers you can from given digits and keeping track of number of operations. Although as a guide, this answer is good enough as I said in previous comment :)

Comment: Is the suggestion that a non-binary tree is created and then at each level the value is calculated for the required value. If the required value is found, then the number of steps are returned. I am not getting that what should be the condition where one knows that the required value cannot be formed and output is -1

Comment: @ShashankShekhar there is maximum amount of operation given in the problem description. For thuis example a depth of 7 would be the maximum... use  thuis to end your calculations. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int n,m,o;
    cin>>n>>m>>o;
    int arr[n];
    queue<pair<int,int>> q;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
        q.push(make_pair(arr[i],1));
    }
    int op[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) cin>>op[i];
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) mp[op[i]]=1;
    int target;
    cin>>target;
    int ans=INT_MAX;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int num=q.front().first;
        int count=q.front().second;
        if(num==target) ans=min(ans,count);
        q.pop();
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(i==0 and count+1<=o)
                {
                    q.push(make_pair(num*10+arr[j],count+1));
                }
                else
                {
                    if(i==1 and mp.find(i)!=mp.end() and count+3<=o)
                    {
                        q.push(make_pair(num+arr[j],count+3));
                    }
                    if(i==2 and mp.find(i)!=mp.end() and count+3<=o)
                    {
                        q.push(make_pair(abs(num-arr[j]),count+3));
                    }
                    if(i==3 and mp.find(i)!=mp.end() and count+3<=o)
                    {
                        q.push(make_pair(num*arr[j],count+3));
                    }
                    if(i==4 and mp.find(i)!=mp.end() and count+3<=o)
                    {
                        q.push(make_pair(num/arr[j],count+3));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(ans==INT_MAX) cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    else cout<<ans<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).