# Create 2 pillars of equal height from an array of bricks

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Problem Statement:

There are N bricks (a1, a2, ...., aN). Each brick has length L1, L2, ...., LN). Make 2 highest parallel pillars (same length pillars) using the bricks provided.

Constraints:

1. There are N bricks.  5<=N<=50
2. Length of each brick.  1<=L<=1000
3. Sum of the bricks lengths <= 1000

Length of the bricks is not given in size order. There may be multiple bricks which may have the same length. Not all bricks have to be used to create the pillars.

Example:

1st Example-

N = 5
2, 3, 4, 1, 6

Possible Sets:
(2, 6) and  (3, 4, 1)

Answer: 8

My Approach:

Finding the maximum possible length of the 2 parallel pillars ie. floor(N/2). Then, using DP to find all the sum lengths that are possible using all the bricks. Starting with the highest possible sum possible <= floor(N/2), I take a single subset of elements that forms the sum. Then, again repeating the DP approach to find if the same sum can be formed using the remaining elements. If it can be formed, then the output is the highest possible sum, else using the 1st DP, check the next highest possible sum that can be formed and then, again iterate the whole process.

The problem with the above approach is that it checks for only one subset of elements to form the required sum. All possible subsets that can form the required sum should be checked and then for each of these subsets, using the remaining elements it should be checked if the same required sum can be formed. The trouble is the implementation of this in my current approach.

2nd Example-

N = 6
3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 1

Possible Sets:
(3, 2, 6) and (7, 4)

Answer: 11

The problem in my code might come in this case depending on the order in which elements (brick lengths) are given as input. It might be possible that the first set is formed using the elements (3, 7, 1) = 11 but the second set (2, 6, 4) cannot form sum = 11. Hence, my code starts to find the next possible maximum sum .ie. 10 which is wrong.

Can someone suggest better approaches or possible improvements in my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this with dynamic programming where for each pair (x, y) you work out whether it is possible to build pillars of length x and y using different bricks from the bricks considered so far.

Consider each brick in turn. At the start only (0, 0) is possible. When you see a brick of length L then for every possible pillar (x, y) there are three descendants - (x, y) (ignore the brick), (x + L, y) (use the brick on the first pillar), and (x, y + L) (use the brick on the second pillar).

So after you have considered all the bricks you will have a long list of possible pairs and you simply choose the pair which has two pillars of the same length and as long as possible. This will be practical as long as there are never too many different pairs (you can remove any duplicates from the list).

Assuming that the brick lengths are integers and the maximum pillar length is 1000 there are only 1001 * 1001 possible pairs, so this should be practical, and in fact it is probably easiest if you store pairs by having an array of size [1001, 1001] and setting entries [x, y] to 1 if pair (x, y) is possible and 0 otherwise.

For the first few steps of the example the reachable states  are

(0,0) considering nothing

(0,3) (3,0) (0,0) considering 3

(0,5) (2,3) (0,3) (5,0) (3,0) (0,2) (2,0) (0,0) considering 3 and 2

The number of reachable states grows very fast at first but since we are only considering values from 0..1000 and we only care about whether an array is reachable or not we can maintain them using a boolean array of dimension 1001x1001

Comment: When I consider a brick, I can either add it in the 1st pillar or the 2nd pillar. How to decide which pillar needs to be choosen. A brick can only be added to either the 1st or the 2nd pillar at a time. So, which brick to be added to which pillar?  Or maybe I am not fully clear at what you are trying to explain. Can you give some visual representation for this (on paper, if possible).

Comment: Or is it that you are talking about the tree approach where the root node is (0, 0) and each node has 2 child nodes where the 1st child is formed by adding the brick to the first element keeping 2nd child as it is and the 2nd child is formed by adding the brick to the 2nd element and keeping the first brick as it is. The problem with this approach is that the space and time complexity will be too high. Space complexity: O(2^N) [Worst Case: 2^50). I am not getting your mentioned DP approach.

Comment: I have added an example to try and clarify things. Because we only care about whether a state is reachable or not we can store this as a boolean array of size 1001x1001. This isn't as complex as a tree because there can be many paths to the same state. For example if we have three bricks of size 1 we get (0,0) -> (0,1) (1,0) (0,0) -> (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (0, 1) (1, 0) (0,0) -> (0,3) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0) (2,0) (1,1) (0,2) (1,0) (0, 1) (0,0) and in fact here there are [(n+1)(n+2)]/2 pairs at step n counting from n=0 until we get to drop states with values > 1000

Comment: Your above suggested solution can be implemented by a queue. Correct? At first only the first element is there in the queue and then it is popped from the queue and the 2 elements (x+L, y) and (x, y+L) are pushed in the queue. For each element, this is repeated and we keep a track of the highest possible same element pair (x, x)

Comment: You could use a queue, but you need some way to detect duplicates with a queue so an array of bytes or bits might be easier, because you can just set elements there and with duplicates you just overwrite locations you have already set. Note that you need to retain old elements so if you start off with (x, y) you should have (x, y) and (x+L, y) and (x, y+L) at the next stage. This accounts for the fact that L might not be used at all in the best solution.

Comment: I mean when (x,y) is processed and removed from the queue, (x+L, y) and (x, y+L) are added to the queue. If (x, y) where x = y is the best solution for the given problem, then in that case it will remain the best solution till the last when all elements have been processed from the queue. I still don't get it why I need to push back (x, y) in the queue again.

Comment: 1 more thing: Won't your solution fail in this case:  1, 5, 3, 2  . Here, answer = 5 . Here, we have to skip 1st element (ie. 1) to get the answer. But, when we implement the solution, we add all the elements one by one starting from the first element.

Comment: The example you give shows why you should leave (0,0) in the queue (or set in the array). If you leave it in after processing 1 it is available to produce (5, 0) after processing 5 and this leads to (5, 3) and then (5,5) which will be recognised as the best answer.

Comment: Got your point. The entries are: (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(5,0),(0,5),(6,0),(1,5),(0,6),(5,1),(3,0),(0,3),(4,0),(1,3),(3,1),(0,4),(8,0),(5,3),(3,5),(0,8),(9,0),(6,3),(4,5),(1,8),(3,6),(0,9),(8,1),(5,4).........Continuing this will give the result (5,5). The number of entries can be reduced to half i believe. There are duplicates. But still the no. of entries is large. For this example containing 4 elements, I am using two 1-D arrays of length 93 elements(>2^4) each. Max. value of n=50. So, won't it lead to segmentation fault.(>2^50) ?

Comment: I am assuming the lengths are integers, and the question says the sum of the bricks length is <= 1000. So the maximum number of different pairs you can have is the number of different pairs of numbers where both elements are integers in the range 0..1000. This is 1001 * 1001

Comment: Got your point. But the way, the way I am trying ie. putting the entries in two 1-d arrays won't work. Any suggestion on how to store these 1001 * 1001 entries? Is it a good option to store these entries as a 1-d array of size 10^6 (same way as system internals store 2-d array by converting in 1-d array)? Starting with the 0th row, all the columns till 1000, then repeating it for the other rows.

Comment: Thank You for the help. Can you please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224443/broken-calculator?noredirect=1#comment73546606_43224443 . I might have some small info missing in the question(don't remember it fully). Others have suggested some approaches. If you can as well suggest some approach.

Comment: there will be total 3^50 combinations. How can it reduce to 1001*1001? I understand that we'll ignore pairs with >1000 value but still we intitally have to pick 3^50 entries to filter out? What am I missing?

Comment: @JerryGoyal we don't have to enumerate all the possible combinations explicitly. We only have to keep track of which pairs of numbers represent two column lengths that we could actually build. We compute the buildable pairs using at most the first brick from the only buildable pair using no bricks (0,0). We compute the buildable pairs using at most the first two bricks from the buildable pairs using at most the first brick, and so on. This part is just like any other instance of dynamic programming.

Comment: @mcdowella Sorry for asking this late but had a query. Can we skip (x+L, y) or (x, y+L) if they are showing up as repeated. I mean if they have already come up before. Won't that lead to loss of solution? Can you please clarify this. Thank You

Comment: @mcdowella For example: for the case -> N= 5   [Bricks: 2, 3, 4, 1, 6] ,  (0,4) is produced by taking 2, 4 but then later it is again produced using 2, 3, 1. If we drop this 2nd (0, 6) , won't it lead to loss of solution?

Comment: @shashank Once you have a pair, such as (0,4), you never drop it but you never need more than one copy of each pair - which is the behaviour you get if you use a boolean array as suggested and set elements to true to indicate that a pair is now possible - setting an element to true twice is the same as setting to true once.

Comment: @mcdowella Yes. Thanks. I got that 'we never drop an element once it is there'. Thank you again for the help. For me, the code works perfectly till N = 27 (array with 27 elements) and the output is correct ( I have verified this) but for N>27 it starts to break (The program simply terminates I guess because of memory issues). In order to have max. 1000*1000 distinct pairs, I need to clear up all the old pairs once I move to a new element. Eg: In array 3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 1   Lets say I move to element 6, as I process previous elements I need to clear them up since they will anyways get copied.

Comment: @mcdowella I used queue from stl with pair as well as vector with pair but for N>27 it fails. queue < pair<int, int> > and vector <pair<int, int> > Do I have better options than using swap to copy the elements from one queue to another so as to clear the memory?

Comment: @shashank you do not need STL. If you simply want to find the maximum possible length you just need an array of booleans of size 1001x1001 which can as you suggest be a 1-d array of that size with element(i,j) at i * 1001 + j. If you need to trace back to find a solution instead use an integer array initialised to -1. Set element(i,j) by setting it to the length that makes it accessible. Then you can trace back these lengths to find the collection of bricks needed.

Comment: @mcdowella I got the first 2 lines. I could not get the last part. I guess you are trying to explain the part of holding the values temporarily so that each of (x, y+L), (x+L, y) and (x, y) can be processed and their processed results (next records) can be made true into 1001*1001 array.

Comment: @mcdowella Let me clarify what I have understood with an example array. N = 3, 2 . Please let me know if I am right or wrong.

Comment: @mcdowella Initial array of 1000*1001 initialized to false. Start with (0, 0) making position 0*1000 + 0 as true. Then for each element added (In this case 3), I put (0,3) ie. position 0*1000 + 3 and (3, 0) ie. position 3*1000 + 0 as true. Now for every new element from the array (in this case 2), I traverse the 1000*1001 array looking for each entry that is true and then for each of those entries (x, y), push true for the pairs (x, y+2) and (x+2, y) at their respective positions into the array. Is this ok?

Comment: @mcdowella   Since the maximum number of elements can be 50, the complexity will be 50 * pow(10, 6)  ie. we iterate 50 times the whole array of size pow(10, 6). Is this ok?

Comment: @shashank If you use an integer array use a standard dynamic programming traceback to recover the solution. Suppose the best answer is at 800,800 and the value stored at 800,800 is 13. Then you can get to 800,800 with the last length used 13 so you must be able to get to 800,787 and 787,800. Choose either of these, say 800,787 and find the value stored there. If this is 12 the the next to last length used was 12 and you must be able to get to one of 800,775 or 788,787. Take whatever of these has a value not -1, look at the value there and carry on. Search for dynamic programming trace back

Answer (score 1):

Recently I tried to solve this problem while preparing for Samsung Competency Test. I build the solution and this might help you guys for your practice. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/240457/mcdowella that I am able to solve this using his strategy.

```
public class Pillars {
    public static int h=0,mh=0; 
    public static void main(String[] args)  {   
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];     
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=scan.nextInt();
            mh+=a[i];
        }
        mh/=2;// the height of the two pillars is the total, then single pillar can't be more than half of total 
        maxHeight(0,0,a,0);
        // if no pillars can be built using the data, this print statement is executed
        System.out.println("Maximum Height Formed with the given Data "+h);     
    }

    public static void maxHeight(int x,int y,int a[],int i)
    {
        if(x==y && x!=0 && x>h)// whether the heights formed are equal or not 
        {
            h=x;
            if(h==mh) // if equal then print and exit the program
            {
                System.out.println("Maximum Height Formed with the given Data "+h);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        if(i<a.length )
        {
            maxHeight(x+a[i],y,a,i+1);
            maxHeight(x,y+a[i],a,i+1);          
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question can be solved simply using recursion. But it will not be efficient for large values for n. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void solve(int a[], int vis[], int p1, int p2, int n, int &ans){
    if(p1 == p2){

        if(p1 > ans){
            ans = p1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){

        if(vis[i] == 0){
            vis[i] = 1;
            solve(a, vis, p1 + a[i], p2, n, ans);
            solve(a, vis, p1, p2 + a[i], n, ans);
            vis[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    int vis[n] = {0};
    int ans = -1;
    solve(a,vis,0,0,n,ans);

    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```